# WCF Could not find endpoint element and contract

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I'm trying to create a WCF and consume it from another C# class.

I think I'm doing everything right but i Get the error message says Contract name is not familiar.

This is my Web.config code:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="PNMSoft.Sequence.Invoices.InvoicesBehavior" name="PNMSoft.Sequence.Invoices.Invoices">
        <endpoint name="InvoicesEndPoint" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PNMSoft.Sequence.Invoices.IInvoices">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="PNMSoft.Sequence.Invoices.InvoicesBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is my interface code:

```
namespace PNMSoft.Sequence.Invoices
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IInvoices
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void SendInvoicesToCustomer(int wfid, int userID, int type, string mail, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string clientCode);

    }
}
```

This is my code when I try to activate a function from the service:

```
InvoicesClient client = new InvoicesClient("InvoicesEndPoint");
client.SendInvoicesToCustomer(IWFID, userID2, type2, Mail, DateFrom2, DateTo2, clientCode2);
```

On the first row I get this error message: "Could not find endpoint element with name 'InvoicesEndPoint' and contract 'Invoices.IInvoices' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.".

This is the config file on my cient's side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="InvoicesEndPoint" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="InvoicesEndPoint" contract="Invoices.IInvoices" name="InvoicesEndPoint">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I guess I need to add something to the config file in my client's side. What should I add?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there a client configuration in your client application? If not then the error is telling you what is missing. If yes can you please add it to the question. You may was to correct the typo `InoicesEndPoint`

Comment: After adding the service reference, does the client application have the client configuration?
Also are you running both the client and service when testing?

Comment: You made a typo somewhere. `InoicesEndPoint` != `InvoicesEndPoint`.

Comment: behaviorConfiguration="PNMSoft.Sequence.Invoices.InvoicesBehavior",rename to something else as both service  behaviorConfiguration and service  name as the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I just had to add the endpoint to the client side's config.